# utf8_unicode_ci: How to support expansions with "Like"?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation, utf8mb4

It states in the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html):

> utf8_unicode_ci supports mappings such as expansions; that is, when one character compares as equal to combinations of other characters. For example, in German and some other languages “ß” is equal to “ss”.

I tried this out with an utf8mb4_unicode_ci collated table, with a row that has the name `Heß`.

```
select * from users where name = "Hess"
```

return the row with `Heß`. However, when I do the same with the like syntax

```
select * from users where name LIKE "%Hess%"
```

it returns no match.

Why does this happen and how does one fix it?

Comment: The algorithm for LIKE is mind-boggling.